# PHP will copy recursive a directory if called via Browser, but not if called via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recursion

I have a php script that need to recursive copy a directory to another. It works if called via browser with get variables, but not if called via ajax.

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 7 for testing purposes.

Is there anything about permissions that i may be missing?

```
    var path = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/wordpress2/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/modules/altera_tema.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            tema: code
        }, 
        complete: function(msg){
            alert(msg.toString());
        }
    });
```

the `code` var is the folder name.

```
  function delete_files($target) {
      if(is_dir($target)){
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned
          foreach( $files as $file ) {
            delete_files( $file );      
          }
          rmdir( $target );
      } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
      }
  }

  function copyr($source, $dest) {
    if (is_file($source)) {
      return copy($source, $dest);
    }
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
      mkdir($dest);
    }
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
      if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
        continue;
      }

      if ($dest !== "$source/$entry") {
         copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
      }
    }
    $dir->close();
    return true;
  }


  delete_files('asdf');
  copyr($_GET['tema'], 'asdf');
```

this is the `PHP` that handles the copy and remove of the files

Actually, if i do an ajax request directly in the chrome console, it works perfectly. But it  wont work via button / onClick()

Comment: Please show your JQuery code...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie added, srry

Comment: @ghaschel Can you share the PHP that is responsible for handling the request? We don't need to see the copying portion (not likely), just the portion that handles the request.

Comment: What is the value of `code`? Are you sure this directly contains the value you expect it to have?

Comment: @JonathanSampson it contains a string with the folder name. Exactly the folder name, nothing less, nothing more

Comment: As its a GET request, it is likely be cached by the browser, so you only get the first request. You need to ensure the server expires the return result to stop caching (or change it to be a POST which never caches). What do you see in Fiddler2 or equivalent network sniffer?

Comment: I just switched it to POST, and i'm getting the exact same result as GET

Answer (score 1):

I would enable logging for XHR requests in Chrome:

[image]

And then inspect the request from the Network tab:

[image]

Make sure that your Request URL matches the url you're manually entering into your browser. Additional data in the Headers panel will help differentiate the two experiences.

If you also enabled *Preserve log upon navigation*, you can manually enter the url again and examine the two requests in your Network tab for any significant differences.

Comment: The not-working preview tab of the XHR request, returns me lots of "no such file or directory", but it is in the correct folder, according to `echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));`

Comment: Sounds like `code` probably doesn't contain what you think it contains. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `tema: code` line and inspecting the value of `code`?

Comment: I tried before using code, displaying an alert box with it's content. And it contains the correct string

Comment: @ghaschel Does it work if you replace `code` with the actual string?

Comment: @ghaschel I wanted to follow up here with you and see how you were doing. If you are still having issues, I'd be happy to assist in debugging via Google Hangout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your request type is "GET" in ajax request. when your receiving as get variables

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: as  Jonathan Sampson pointed out this assumption is wrong.*

i would recommend to add the data parameter directly into the url.
Maybe jquery ignores the data: option, assuming it contains post data.

Comment: jQuery doesn't assume it's POST data. From the docs: "Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests."

Comment: just an idear... then forget it xD